# Correct way to initialize a member struct

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14

Let's say I have the following code: (note that I cannot change the declaration of Vec2)

**Exhibit A**

```
struct Vec2 {
  float x;
  float y;
};

class C {
  struct Data {
    Vec2 v1;
    Vec2 v2;
    int n = 0;
  };
  Data _data;

  C() : _data() {}
};
```

This appears to correctly initialize the two Vec2 structs in Data to zero values. Why does this happen? Does the initialization in C's constructor initializer list handle this?

Would a more correct form use uniform initialization syntax like so?

**Exhibit B**

```
class C {
  struct Data {
    Vec2 v1{};
    Vec2 v2{};
    int n{};
  };
  Data _data;

  C() {}
};
```

---

This leads to my 2nd question--does `_data` need to go in the constructor's initializer list if its constructor takes no arguments? Or is the compiler expected to implicitly handle initialization? I noted that, when using the declaration in exhibit A, but leaving out the initializer list in the constructor, on the VC++ compiler, it seems like it does, however, on Clang, it appears the data is uninitialized.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the standard would specify the behavior of this, however the one thing I noticed about you trying to initialize your member structs is that your structs do not have a declared default constructor.

Comment: So are constructors the preferred method, versus modern C++ uniform initializers?

Comment: I think it depends on the actual need and requirements within the source; both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help but if you were to add default constructors to your structures then you should be able to do something as such:

```
struct Vec2 {
  float x;
  float y;
  Vec2() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f) {}
};

class C {
  struct Data {
    Vec2 v1;
    Vec2 v2;
    int n;

    Data() : v1( Vec2() ), v2( Vec2() ), n(0) {}
  };
  Data _data;

  C() : _data( Data() ) {}
};
```

---

**EDIT**

The OP mentioned that he can not modify `Vec2` so indirectly what could be done is:

```
#include "Vec2"

class MyVec2 : public Vec2 {
public:
   MyVec2() : x(0), y(0) {}
};
```

Then you should be able to use your defined version of `Vec2` and its constructors. The rest of the code would remain the same however this may lead to a problem since the base class doesn't have its own `default constructor`.

Comment: This would work, but I can't modify Vec2 for other reasons. I guess I could memset in Data's constructor or say "v1 = {0};"

Comment: @unixunited Oh I see and if you can't modify `Vec2` then maybe what you could do is inherit from `Vec2` and define your own class that is a derivative where you can create your own constructors.